# Apps updating their website

Tags: java, javascript, android, html, mysql

I have an app [Android] that will basically give me numbers and I need those numbers to be sent to a website hosted via "Apache" (Haven't worked that out yet).

The reason why I am asking it here is because I do not know the first thing about making applications connect to a website in way where it updates a variable each time it is calculated on that app.

Any few tips or advises would be great! [I know how to use HTML, a bit of java scripting, MySQL and lots of java]

What language should I be using. How does the server work and how do we make the app and the website work concurrently, or in parallel?

Comment: Your question is very generic... there are many, many options you could use for a server, and a good answer depends on knowing which server you're going to use.  Connecting your app to a website could be as simple as making GET requests from your app, or it could be more complicated if you choose a more complex server setup.  Could you provide more information about how you want to setup your server?

Comment: Forgive me. like i said, i have zero knowledge on designing or making applications. What I need is an advice. what do you think about using apache? Just advice on how can it be done.

Answer (score 0):

This is question is too broad, still I am listing few ways

1. Generate the data on application
2. Send a custom broadcast whenever the data is generated.
3. Start an Intent service from the Broadcast Receiver.
4. Post to server i.e to a REST or SOAP service using Http post and basic name value pairs.

At your server side, you need a service which receives the posted data and saves it to the database or any where you want.